# JOOQ Cast String to Enum with Converter

Tags: java, sql-server, enums, jooq

While looking for a way to cast my String field into an Enum i stubled across the `.cast()` Method.  When called it throws an `SQLDialectNotSupportedException`.
Dialect has been Set to `SQLSERVER2014` in the Context `DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.SQLSERVER2014);`.
The corresponding line:

```
create.select( ... lecture.DAY_OF_WEEK.cast(DayOfWeek.class), ... );
```

The full Error:

```
org.jooq.exception.SQLDialectNotSupportedException: Type class java.time.DayOfWeek is not supported in dialect null
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:944)
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:880)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractField.cast(AbstractField.java:256)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.Classes.Startup.getStandardExample(Startup.java:218)
at de.esteam.lecturedb.jooq.Classes.Startup.main(Startup.java:54)
```

I tried to achieve a conversion to the Enum with a Converter but i cannot get it running.

Is there a way to get the Converter into the `cast()` or is there another way to get the String into the Enum I cannot find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `cast()` here because that would require jOOQ to understand how to cast your data type to your custom type *in SQL*. What you want to do is a client side conversion, and that is achieved ideally using a `Converter`.

Once you have implemented your `Converter`, the recommended way to use it is to attach it to generated code using the code generator:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types

```xml
<forcedType>
  <userType>java.time.DayOfWeek</userType>
  <converter>com.example.YourConverter</converter>
  <includeExpression>(?i:DAY_OF_WEEK)</includeExpression>
</forcedType>
```

If that's not an option, you can create a "converted" field reference as follows:

```
// I'm assuming you're storing the data as an INTEGER
DataType<DayOfWeek> type = SQLDataType.INTEGER.asConvertedDataType(new YourConverter());
Field<DayOfWeek> field = DSL.field("{0}", type, lecture.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// And now use that instead
create.select(field)...
```

But I really recommend attaching the converter to the generated code for most convience.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for.

But i cannot use the first Method (right now) so it has to be the second one.

I created the Converter

```public class DOWConverter extends EnumConverter<Integer, DayOfWeek>  {

        public DOWConverter()
        {
            super(Integer.class, DayOfWeek.class);           
        }       
        
    }```
But i get the error: ```No closing instance of type QueryFeaturesTask is accessible``` on  the ```new DOWConverter()``` from your suggestion

Comment: @recklessGreed: Can you please ask a new question? The comment section is not very good for code and debugging that code...

Comment: Of course! Thank you in advance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586868/jooq-cast-string-to-enum-with-converter-inline