# JOOQ Cast String to Enum with Converter inline

Tags: java, sql-server, enums, jooq

As asked here the follow up Question to this [#58538732](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58538732/jooq-cast-string-to-enum-with-converter)

As suggested by Lukas Eder I wrote an `EnumConverter` to convert the `Integer` to a `DayOfWeek`

```
public class DOWConverter extends EnumConverter<Integer, DayOfWeek>  {

    public DOWConverter()
    {
        super(Integer.class, DayOfWeek.class);           
    }               
}
```

The `select` now looks the following

```
DataType<DayOfWeek> typeDOW = SQLDataType.INTEGER.asConvertedDataType(new DOWConverter() /*ERROR*/);
Field<DayOfWeek> fieldDOW = DSL.field("{0}", typeDOW, lecture.DAY_OF_WEEK);

create.select( ..., fieldDOW, ...)...
```

With the Error Message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>   No enclosing instance of type QueryFeaturesTask is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type QueryFeaturesTask (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of QueryFeaturesTask).

As stated, using the Converter at CodeGen Time is currently not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you placed your `DOWConverter` inside of another class, thus creating an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). I recommend you place the converter at the top level, in its own file, making it a top level class. If you must create a nested class, make sure it is not an inner class by making it static:

```
public class Enclosing {
    // Make this class here static:
    public static class DOWConverter extends EnumConverter<Integer, DayOfWeek> {
        public DOWConverter() {
            super(Integer.class, DayOfWeek.class);           
        }               
    }
}
```

[Oracle's tutorial on nested classes explains this really well](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).